# Using Java Optional within stream mapping

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type, null-check

I have code like this:

```
public void processList(List<String> list) {

    for (String item : list) {
        Object obj = getObjectForString(item);
        if (obj != null) {
            doSomethingWithObject(obj);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Object was null for " + item);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I would like to streamline this and avoid the `null` check using `list.stream().map( *blah, blah, blah* )`, and `doSomethingWithObject` if the object is not `null`, but log the error otherwise (by using the `orElse` method on an optional).  I'm not super savvy with this Java 8 functionality and not sure if there is a nice, slick way to do what I want here or not.  Suggestions?

Edit to add a failed attempt at this:

```java
list.stream()
    .map(p -> getObjectForString(p))
    .map(Optional::ofNullable)
    .forEach(
        p -> p.ifPresentOrElse(
            r -> doSomethingWithObject(r),
            () -> System.err.println("Object was null")
        ));
```

Even if that code behaved the way I want, it still doesn't append the String from the original list to the error message as I would like it to.  But maybe that's too much complexity to try to accomplish with streams like this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A big part of being a good software developer is having the curiosity and initiative play with things to see how they work.  I suggest that you read the relevant Javadoc (you do seem to have a basic grasp of streams, which is good), try some experiments, and when you find some behavior you don't understand, THEN ask a specific question.

Comment: Here was a failed attempt:  `
list.stream().map(p -> getObjectForString(p)).map(Optional::ofNullable).forEach(
            p -> p.ifPresentOrElse(
                r -> doSomethingWithObject(r),
                () -> System.err.println("Object was null")
            ));`
It looks like doSomethingWithObject is being called twice for each item in the list (including when the object is null).  I do get one output of the error message for one null object, so that is good.  But I am also not getting the String "item" appended to my error message as I would like (that may be the trickiest part)

Comment: Trying to properly edit the formatting of my previous comment.  BUT, it timed out.  Sorry about that mess.

Comment: @Adam, you could paste your failed attempt and related information as part of the question itself.

Comment: There is no sense in mapping to an `Optional`. Just use `.filter(item -> getObjectForString(item) == null)`

Comment: @Holger, but the point is if the object is null, then I want to log a message. Can't do that if I filter those out, right?

Comment: @GauthamM, good suggestion - added to the question.

Comment: The predicate passed to `filter` tells which elements to keep. The logic of `.filter( /* tell which elements should pass */) .forEach( /* tell what to do with the elements that passed the filter */)` should be easy to understand. But anyway, look at your attempt, and ask yourself, letting aside that it didn’t work that way, is this in any way simpler than your original loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we should propagate the `item` even after conversion. The slick way is using tuple or pair.

I used Tuple from vavr functional library to do the same. And below is the code for your reference

```
list.stream()
                .map(p -> Tuple.of(p, getObjectForString(p)).map2(Optional::ofNullable))
                .forEach(p -> p._2.ifPresentOrElse(
                            r -> doSomethingWithObject(r),
                            () -> System.err.println("Object was null" + p._1))
                );
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got sidetracked on this, but just now came back to it.  I got it to do what I want using Pair.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the below method does not avoid a `null` check as you wanted in your question, this is just another way to achieve the same result. (Only benefit is that it saves 1-2 lines of code!).

The below code uses `Runnable` (takes no arguments and returns nothing as well) along with Java 8's `Function`.

**NOTE :** I would still recommend the normal `for` loop :-), as I believe that the below might look fancy, but the `for` loop is more easy to understand in this particular case.

```java
Function<String, Runnable> func = item -> {
    Object obj = getObjectForString(item);
    return (obj != null) ? ( () -> doSomethingWithObject(obj))
                         : ( () -> System.err.println("Object was null for " + item));        
};

list.stream().map(func).forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to collect the items in to separate 2 buckets/partitions based on if the item had an associated object or not.  After that, process the 2 buckets as required:

```
final Boolean HAS_OBJECT = Boolean.FALSE;

Map<Boolean, List<String>> partitionedMap = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(item -> !Objects.isNull(getObjectForString(item))));

partitionedMap.get(HAS_OBJECT).stream()
    .map(item -> getObjectForString(item))
    .forEach(obj -> doSomethingWithObject(obj));

partitionedMap.get(!HAS_OBJECT)
    .forEach(item -> System.err.println("Object was null for " + item));
```

Comment: I think the `doSomethingWithObject` is to be done on the object returned from `getObjectForString(item)`

Comment: @Gautham M : thanks - I missed that; code corrected.